# Model from IEnumerable<model> to controller without reloading page aspnet core

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Goal: I have an ecommerce website. I'm working on the cart page. When the user wants to add one or remove one from the quantity they're buying, I want them to be able to press a plus or minus button on the page that will remove or add one without reloading the page.

Issue:
I have controllers to make this happen, but I don't know how to pass a specific model or the ID from the model, from the foreach loop all without reloading the page.

Here's the page:

```
@model IEnumerable<AirmotionEcommerceWebsite.TwebCartProduct>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Cart";

    ViewBag.decSubtotal = 0;
    ViewBag.decShipping = 68.99;
    ViewBag.decStateTax = 0.078;
    ViewBag.decTax = 0;
    ViewBag.decTotal = 0;
}

<br />
<div class="container">
    <h2>Cart</h2>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="align-content-lg-start table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                            @if (Model.Count() == 0)
                            {
                                <h1>Your cart is empty!</h1>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    ViewBag.decSubtotal += item.IntQuantity * item.IntWebProduct.DecMsrp;

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-left">@item.IntWebProduct.StrProductName</td>
                                        <td class="text-left">@item.IntWebProduct.DecMsrp.ToString("c")</td>
                                        <td class="text-left">
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            @Html.ActionLink("add_circle_outline", "AddOneToCart", new { intWebProductID = item.IntWebProductId }, new { @class = "material-icons" })
                                            @item.IntQuantity.ToString()
                                            @Html.ActionLink("remove_circle_outline", "RemoveOneFromCart", new { intWebProductID = item.IntWebProductId }, new { @class = "material-icons" })
                                            @Html.ActionLink("delete", "RemoveAllFromCart", new { intWebProductID = item.IntWebProductId }, new { @class = "material-icons float-right" })
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h2>Order Summary</h2>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        @{
                            //ViewBag.decTax = ViewBag.decSubtotal * (decimal)ViewBag.decStateTax;
                            ViewBag.decTotal = (decimal)ViewBag.decSubtotal + (decimal)ViewBag.decShipping;/* + ViewBag.decTax;*/
                        }
                        <li class="list-group-item">Subtotal<span class="float-right">@ViewBag.decSubtotal.ToString("c")</span></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Shipping<span class="float-right">@ViewBag.decShipping.ToString("c")</span></li>
                        @*<li class="list-group-item">Tax<span class="float-right">@ViewBag.decTax.ToString("c")</span></li>*@
                    <li class="font-weight-bold list-group-item">
                        Total<span class="float-right">@ViewBag.decTotal.ToString("c")</span>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        @Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "Checkout", "Home")
                    </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want them to be able to press a plus or minus button on the page that will remove or add one without reloading the page.

Firstly,you can use js to change the html code.But you cannot use set ViewBag with js variable,so when checkout,you need to use url to pass `decSubtotal` and `decTotal`.Here is a demo:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Cart";

    ViewBag.decSubtotal = 0;
    ViewBag.decShipping = 68.99;
    ViewBag.decStateTax = 0.078;
    ViewBag.decTax = 0;
    ViewBag.decTotal = 0;
}

<br />
<div class="container">
    <h2>Cart</h2>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="align-content-lg-start table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <tbody>
                            @if (Model.Count() == 0)
                            {
                                <h1>Your cart is empty!</h1>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    ViewBag.decSubtotal += item.IntQuantity * item.IntWebProduct.DecMsrp;

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-left">@item.IntWebProduct.StrProductName</td>
                                        <td class="text-left">@item.IntWebProduct.DecMsrp.ToString("c")</td>
                                        <td class="text-left">

                                            <button onclick="Add(this,@item.IntWebProduct.DecMsrp)" class = "material-icons">add_circle_outline</button>
                                            <span>@item.IntQuantity</span>
                                            <button onclick="Remove(this,@item.IntWebProduct.DecMsrp)">remove_circle_outline</button>
                                            <button onclick="Delete(this,@item.IntWebProduct.DecMsrp)">RemoveAllFromCart</button>

                                          
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h2>Order Summary</h2>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        @{
                            //ViewBag.decTax = ViewBag.decSubtotal * (decimal)ViewBag.decStateTax;
                            ViewBag.decTotal = (decimal)ViewBag.decSubtotal + (decimal)ViewBag.decShipping;/* + ViewBag.decTax;*/
                        }
                        <li class="list-group-item">Subtotal<span class="float-right" id="Subtotal">@ViewBag.decSubtotal.ToString("c")</span></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Shipping<span class="float-right" id="Shipping">@ViewBag.decShipping.ToString("c")</span></li>
                        @*<li class="list-group-item">Tax<span class="float-right">@ViewBag.decTax.ToString("c")</span></li>*@
                        <li class="font-weight-bold list-group-item">
                            Total<span class="float-right" id="Total">@ViewBag.decTotal.ToString("c")</span>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                           
                            <a id="Checkout" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Checkout">Checkout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        var decSubtotal = @ViewBag.decSubtotal;
        var decShipping =@ViewBag.decShipping;
        var decTotal=@ViewBag.decTotal;
        function Add(t, price) {
            decSubtotal += price;
            change();
            $(t).next()[0].innerText = parseInt($(t).next()[0].innerText) + 1;
            
        }
        function Remove(t, price) {
            decSubtotal -= price;
            change();
            if (parseInt($(t).prev()[0].innerText) == 1) {
                $(t).parent().parent().remove();
            } else {
                $(t).prev()[0].innerText = parseInt($(t).prev()[0].innerText) - 1;

            }
            
        }
        function Delete(t, price) {
            decSubtotal -= parseInt($(t).prev().prev()[0].innerText) * price;
            change();
            $(t).parent().parent().remove();
        }
        function change() {
            decTotal = decSubtotal + decShipping;
            var temp = document.getElementById("Subtotal").innerText.substr(0, 1);
            document.getElementById("Subtotal").innerText = temp + decSubtotal.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById("Total").innerText = temp + decTotal.toFixed(2);
            if ($("#Checkout").attr("href").includes("?")) {
                href = href.split("?")[0];
            }
            $("#Checkout").attr("href",href + "?decSubtotal=" + decSubtotal.toFixed(2) + "&&decTotal=" + decTotal.toFixed(2));
        }
    </script>
}
```

action:

```
 public IActionResult Checkout(decimal decSubtotal, decimal decTotal)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]